# Can't get ssh-keygen to complete using Powershell

Tags: powershell, ssh-keygen

all - I'm trying to generate ssh keys using powershell with the following but PS just sits there on 'Generating public/private ...' message and never finishes, does not prompt for anything and does not display any sort of error.  Anyone have any ideas why this might not be completing?

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519
```

Generating public/private ed25519 key pair.`

Comment: Hmm. it seems to be happening to [other people as well](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/836). Can you try runnig it in cmd? btw, `Get-Command ssh-keygen` tells us it's an executable and not a `cmdlet` or `Alias`.

Comment: It worked from the command line.  I appreciate the response and advice.

Comment: Your command triggers interactive prompts. The only environment in which PowerShell normally has a problem with interactive prompts is the ISE, which fundamentally doesn't support interactive console applications. That, among other reasons, not least its obsolescent status, is why the ISE should be avoided - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375).

Comment: Got it.  I was using ISE so, that would probably explain it.

Comment: So, now(sorry, I'm a newbie here).  I want to be able to use these keys to securely login into nearly 440 servers to pull down some backups to a local backup server.  I've tried a few things that I found out there in the 'wild' but, do any of you experts have any advice, able to point me in the right direction?  I can post another question if need be.

Comment: @SteveMueller, yes, please post a new question (and search the existing ones first, perhaps your question has already been answered).